# Script which will move non-ASCII files

Tags: bash, grep

I need help. I should write a script,whih will move all non-ASCII files from one directory to another. I got this code,but i dont know why it is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in "/home/osboxes/Parkhom"/*
do
   if [ -eq "$( echo "$(file $file)" | grep -nP '[\x80-\xFF]' )" ];
   then
      if test -e "$1"; then
         mv $file $1
      fi
   fi
done
exit 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "non-ASCII" file? Are you looking for files that contain bytes that fall outside the realm of 7-bit ASCII? If the code you are running is not working, what does it do instead of working? Are there errors you can add to your question? Please have a look at [**how-to-ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on improving this question, as well as the help on creating an [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This code moves all files...instead ASCII or non-ASCII

Comment: Code should find ASCII files in folder or non-ASCII and move them

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which one you are after, but:

• To test if the *variable* `$file` contains a non-ASCII character, you can do:

```
if [[ $file == *[^[:ascii:]]* ]]; then
```

• To test if the *file* `$file` contains a non-ASCII character, you can do:

```
if grep -qP '[^[:ascii:]]' "$file"; then
```

So for example your code would look like:

```
for file in "/some/path"/*; do
    if grep -qP '[^[:ascii:]]' "$file"; then
        test -d "$1" && mv "$file" "$1"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I need to move all non-ASCII files from directory i wrote in a code to directory i will write in terminal

Comment: So my code will look like this ? 
`#!/bin/bash
for file in "/home/osboxes/Parkhom"/*
do
   if [ -eq "$( echo "$(file $file)" | grep -qP '[^[:ascii:]]' "$file" )" ];
   then
      if test -e "$1"; then
         mv $file $1
      fi
   fi
done
exit 0`

Comment: Great! Make sure to vote on and mark the answer as resolved if it works for you.

Comment: @GrishaLevit, note that `grep -P` is non-portable, and unnecessary with the RE that you've used in your answer. Character classes are even supported in BRE, so plain old `grep` should do just fine.

Comment: Also, I would recommend adjusting the OP's test condition to `test -d "$1"` so that he doesn't risk moving every file in his source directory to the same target filename.

Comment: @ghoti BRE's have character classes but `[:ascii:]` seems to be a PCRE addition.  I guess you can avoid `-P` by using `grep -q $'[^\x01-\x7F]' "$file"` instead, though that would match `\0`.

Comment: @GrishaLevit - ah, right you are - the POSIX class I was thinking of was `[:print:]`. I guess a concern with `[:ascii:]` is that you'd include non-printable characters ... but that's not a concern that the OP has expressed, so .. never mind. :-)  My only suggestion at this point would be that you include mention that your solution only works with Linux variants of GNU grep, as the version of grep in BSD and OSX does not include a `-P` option (though `pcregrep` exists as a separate installable package).

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that your first if statement has an invalid test clause. The `-eq` operator of `[` needs to take one argument before and one after; your before argument is gone or empty.

The second problem is that I think the `echo` is redundant.

The third problem is that the `file` command always has ASCII output but you're checking for binary output, which you'll never see.

Using `file` pretty smart for this application, although there are two ways you can go on this; `file` says a variety of things and what you're interested in are `data` and `ASCII`, but not all files that don't identify as `data` are ASCII and not all files that don't identify as `ASCII` are data.  You might be better off going with the original idea of using `grep`, unless you need to support Unicode files. Your `grep` is a bit strange to me so I don't know what your environment is but I might try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in "/home/osboxes/Parkhom"/*
do
  if grep -qP '[\0x80-\0xFF]' $file; then
    [ -e "$1" ] && mv $file $1
  fi
done
```

The `-q` option means be quiet, only return a return code, don't show the matches.  (It might be `-s` in your `grep`.)  The return code is tested directly by the `if` statement (no need to use `[` or `test`). The `&&` in the next line is just a quick way of saying if the left-hand side is true, then execute the right-hand side. You could also form this as an `if` statement if you find that clearer.  `[` is a synonym for `test`.  Personally if `$1` is a directory and doesn't change, I'd check it once at the beginning of the script instead of on each file, it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to know if something is not a plain text file then you can use the `file` command which returns information about the type of a file.

```
[[ ! $( file -b "$file" ) =~ (^| )text($| ) ]]
```

The `-b` simply tells it not to bother returning the filename.

The returned value will be something like:

```
ASCII text
HTML document text
POSIX shell script text executable
PNG image data, 21 x 34, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Mon Oct 31 14:29:59 2016
```

The regular expression will check whether the returned file information includes the word "text" that is included for all plain text file types.

You can instead filter for specific file types like "ASCII text" if that is all you need.